# Active user meaning when combine all togethers?

Tags: seo, google, google-analytics

I know active users is unique users that in the data range visit our site. but my misunderstanding point is that what is the interpretation when we use 1-day, 7-day, 14-day together? what is the meaning? each point when click by mouse show a one day, I couldn't get the point.  is there any better meaning?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start out: the [Google Analytics Active User report documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6171863?hl=en). It may be helpful, but it doesn't really answer your question.

For completeness, let's go through the graph itself to start: Each day along the graph is giving the user count for the time ranges ending on that day. So in your screenshot, in March 8-14 there were 27 active users, and in March 3-9 there were 51 (the number in the popup: 7 days ending on March 9).

The graph then shows you the pattern of those running totals. I would mostly use this myself to view, say, the 7-day total by itself on the graph, to see traffic trends with the day-to-day changes smoothed out.

One use I could think of for viewing more than one line together is this: Suppose you were looking at your 28-day active users on the graph, and the total went up. By graphing the 1-day active users at the same time, you could see whether it was due to a big spike in traffic on one day, or a smaller increase that lasted longer.

Comment: is it possible more clear the last sentence?

Comment: Maybe. :-) I was thinking that a big increase in one day's traffic would push the 28-day total upward for a while (until it was 29 days old), but smaller increases for more days would also push the 28-day total upward. The 28-day total graph might show you by itself whether it was a big one-day increase, or a smaller multi-day increase, but if it wasn't clear which one, adding the 1-day total would certainly tell you.